# bot pathing for CS:Source

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-source

When I load up a new map in CS:Source it has to spend some time analyzing it before it can be played with bots.

On more complex maps, this can take quite a bit of time. And if I go to play on another computer, I have to do the process over again.

Is there a file associated with each map's analysis that I can copy from computer to computer along with the maps themselves?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured this out for myself. The app creates a .nav file with the same name as the map. Copy these along with your maps and you're good to go.